# Dynamic measure that responds to dynamic dimension

Tags: dynamic, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, dimension

I'll try to describe this scenario without introducing too much irrelevant info, but keeping it simple.

Using the newish Field Parameter feature in PowerBI, I created a Parameter called _Dimensions and another one called _Measures, selecting common columns in the former and common measures in the latter.

I then build a bar chart with [_Dimension Fields] for X-Axis, [_Measure Fields] for Y-axis, and a single-select slicer for each. Now when user selects a measure and a column, it draws a bar chart of their selected measure, sliced by their selected dimension.

What I'd like to do is actually make this a Pareto chart, which would entail putting in a second measure on Y-axis, but rather than having a pareto counterpart to every possible measure a user may select, I'd like to create a single measure that calculates running percent of total of [selected measure] along [selected dimension].

I was hopeful I could call the [_Dimension Fields] column that PowerBI created with its special properties from DAX, but that doesn't seem to treat them any different than any other column. I also tried NAMEOF, but that just returns a string. I was hoping it would act like INDIRECT does in Excel, treating the string as a reference, but alas.

Does the above problem statement make sense? Can anyone describe an elegant design approach to do this dynamically that does not involve just writing a version of every possible measure a user could select and then use a switch?

imagining the combo chart to look like this (pareto measure in line chart part)

[image]

edit: secondary question, but equally important to the end goal of a fully functional dynamic pareto: when user selects measure, I want the selected dimension to always be sorted desc by selected measure. This is how you do a pareto analysis, but PBI does not default to sort descending always, and each time you change the dimension (via slicer click) the chart resets sorting. Any way to ensure that the sort order is fixed correctly?

Comment: This is what calculation groups are for. Have a look at Tabular Editor.

Comment: good thought. Unfortunately won't work in my case because the report is built on a central data model, and the calculation group would entail editing that central shared model. I do tend to forget about this hidden feature though, so good to be reminded it's out there.

Comment: calculation groups truly are a good approach. I'll explore if it warrants adding to data model. This requirement is for a single report, where the data model supports hundreds of reports. Not sure this would ever get used identically for other reports permanently complicating the shared model.

Comment: @David - add your comment as a response and I will mark as answered. This is the best answer, whether or not it will work in my setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculation groups are the way to go and Tabular Editor is used to create these.

Comment: this is the closest I've been able to find for "elegant", in any case. However, for the purpose of Pareto, the pareto calculation includes both [selectedmeasure] and [selectedcolumn]. Is there an analog for SELECTEDMEASURE() that you know of that dynamically substitutes columns? The referenced Field Parameter feature in PBI does that on a visual, but I need to do that inside of a DAX measure. Any followup ideas?

Comment: Can't your selected column also be a calculation group? I'm struggling to "imagine" a solution without a working sample.

Comment: user could use any column from any table. I could write a calculation group for a bunch of dimensions, I suppose, but that's more or less the same problem. I'd be writing a custom calculation for each dimension that could possible be used in conjunction with a measure. Doesn't dynamically use whatever column user puts in the viz. In Tableau terms (if you are familiar), this would be defined as a table calculation, where it calculates over whatever dimension is on the table, rather than defining a specific named column in the calculation.

Comment: visual aid: https://gifyu.com/image/SNVIE   Looking to add line to the chart, which is running sum of [measure] over [dimension] (as percent of total)

Comment: Can you not see the column in question with isFiltered() or isInScope(). You could potentially use those in your calculation group. I'd really need a sample file in order to be able to work through and test it though. You could try making a minimal reproducible .pbix. Might also be worth posting as a new question in case others have ideas.

Answer (score 0):

After much exploration, here is my solution. It's not 100% dynamic in that it requires writing custom DAX for each dimension and measure that you need to be available for dynamic use, but gets the job done for the scope of the report in question.

1. create field parameter from columns that I will want to dynamically use in viz: name it _Dimension
2. In my example, I will be using two columns from two tables: Carrier[CarrierNumber] and ShipmentLane[LaneCity]
3. create field parameter from measures that I will want to dynamically use in viz: name it _Measure
4. in my example, I have two measures I will want to be able to toggle between: Events_Late and Events_Late2. Both exist on OnTimePerformanceDetail table.
5. create measure to dynamically return value based on the selection of
   _Measure in slicer on canvas. This seems like it should not be unnecessary with field parameter feature, but it is necessary for reasons that will be
   clear if you try to do this without a custom measure.

[image: dynamic measure]

6. create a pareto measure for *each* of the dimensions that may be
   dynamically passed to viz. Each of these dynamically evaluates the base measure, but is specific to a single column for which the measure evaluates over:

[image: carrier Pareto]
[image: lane pareto]

7. create a dynamic pareto measure that chooses the correct pareto calculation based on the selection on _Dimension

[image: dynamic pareto for discrete dimensions]

8. create single select Slicers for _Dimension and _Measure
9. create combo chart, using _Dimension for X-axis, _Measure for Y-axis, and DynamicPareto for line Y-Axis. I have aliased DynamicPareto on the viz to Running% so that it shows nicely and clearly on legend

   [image: pareto chart viz]
10. set the sort order of the chart to be ASC by Dynamic Pareto measure. This ensures that the dimension on X-axis is always sorted correctly

A few notes:

- I named the dynamic pareto as "Discrete" because this only works as
  designed when doing pareto on a discrete dimension, where the bars
  are meant to be sorted desc by [measure]. If you are doing a
  Percentile chart, which is basically the same thing, but the
  dimension is sorted by dimension value instead of measure value, the
  Pareto calculation needs to work slightly differently.
- There are lots of Pareto measure patterns out there. I used the one
  from this    blog, because it's concise and performs well:
  https://janizajcbi.com/2018/08/22/pareto-rule-abc-class-in-dax/
- it is important that the slicers be set to single select
- I discovered there is a Pareto 3rd party viz that is simple and
  dynamic, but has very limited formatting features. Fine for quick
  analysis, but if you have branding or formatting standards, it may
  prove unusable, as in my case
- in my production use case, I have a lot more dimensions and a lot
  more measures that will be available. Started with just 2+2 to prove
  out functionality. Just need to follow same pattern to add more
  available dimensions and measures to mix.
- my naming convention of * suffix is because this report is built on a
  centralized data model. The * makes it easy to find measures that are
  local to this report and not a base measure in the model I am
  connected to.
- the field parameter feature can only be used with a remote model like this if the preview feature of Use Direct Query for AAS and PBI datasets is enabled OR the field parameters are added to the base model. In my case, I'm adding the field parameters to the base model, and all of the measures here are local to the report, connected to remote model.